# Get database row after insert in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

At the moment I have a script where I add data to the database.

Once the data is entered I would like to get the get the row straight away.

For example if I have a query like this where I have two seperate:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO  table SET columnA '".$this->db->escape($columnA)."'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->db->row;
```

I want to be able to make get that database row instantly after inserting it.  Will I have to make a whole new query or is there a quicker way? I am using OpenCarts API if that helps.

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES ('a','b','c');
SELECT * FROM table WHERE your_table_primary_key = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

PHP:

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO  table SET columnA '".$this->db->escape($columnA)."';";
$sql .= "SELECT * FROM table WHERE your_table_primary_key = LAST_INSERT_ID();"
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->db->row;
```

Comment: Do I just insert this in the one query?

Comment: I think if you are using mysqli, you can execute this in one call using [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: It isn't working? I even tryed print_r(LAST_INSERT_ID); both upper and lowercase

Comment: @Peter - Break it into two queries. It appears that you're using the mysql_* functions, which do not support two queries in one call.

Comment: @PeterStuart i updated my answer. try it. `print_r(LAST_INSERT_ID)` - is wrong because `LAST_INSERT_ID` is a MySQL function, not PHP

Comment: @PeterStuart and please mind `id` is only example. You should replace it to your table primary key